# Making Multiple Http Calls and Consolidating Results with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Ok I have found similar problems answered to my problem but not exactly.

Examples:

[Nodejs making parallel http calls and consolidate the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318638/nodejs-making-parallel-http-calls-and-consolidate-the-result)

[Node.js - wait for multiple async calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008479/node-js-wait-for-multiple-async-calls)

I have 8 functions the do the same thing except hit a different api endpoint. In those functions I look at the response and pick out what I want and return. Then I have a function that uses [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) to make all the calls at once and wait for their responses.

This is what 1 of 8 functions look like (pretty much just swap out the api it is hitting).

```
function getMorphite(){
request.get(crestMarketHistoryMorphite , function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        var content = JSON.parse(body);
        var topMorphiteBuy;
        var maxBuy = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < content.items.length; i++){
            var item = content.items[i];
            if(item.location.id == 60003760){
                var buyPrice = item.price;
                if(buyPrice > maxBuy){
                    maxBuy = buyPrice;
                    topMorphiteBuy = item;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(topMorphiteBuy);
        return topMorphiteBuy
    } else {
        console.error(error);
        return error;
    }
});
}
```

And here is my function grabbing all of my functions, running them, and grabbing their responses.

```
exports.getSearchResults = function (req, res) {
var allItems = [];
Promise.all([getTritanium(), getPyrite(), getMexallon(), getIsogen(), getNocxium(), getZydrine(), getMegactye(), getMorphite()]).then(function (response) {
    console.log("Response", response);
    allItems.push(response[0]);
    allItems.push(response[1]);
    allItems.push(response[2]);
    allItems.push(response[3]);
    allItems.push(response[4]);
    allItems.push(response[5]);
    allItems.push(response[6]);
    allItems.push(response[7]);
    res.type('application/json');
    res.json(allItems);
});
};
```

So this 'works' but im having some return problems. Right now the response in is an array of 8 items of undefined. What the heck am I missing here. It has to be a return problem but I feel like I have panic switched around all return statements with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all()` only waits for the async operations if you pass it an array of promises where each promise is linked to a corresponding operation.  Right now, you're passing it an array of `undefined` values because your `getMorphite()` function and the others like it do not actually return anything.  The `return` statements from inside the ``request.get()`callback happen after`getMorphite()`has already long since returned and those return values just go back into the bowels of the`request()` implementation and are ignored.

Because you're passing `Promise.all()` an array of undefined values, it doesn't wait for anything and it doesn't get any results.  So, it calls its `.then()` handler immediately and has nothing but the array of `undefined` values for its results.

If you want to use `Promise.all()` for this (it is the right right tool for the job), then you need to "promisify" your `request()` operations so they return a promise that is resolved with the final result when the async operation is done.  Then, `Promise.all()` will be given an array of promises and `Promise.all().then()` will wait for all the promises to be done and will be given an array of results from those promises.

If you're using Bluebird, you can use it to Promisify the `request.get()` operation like this:

```
 var request = Promise.promisifyAll(request, {multiArgs: true});
```

This "promisifyAll" step adds new methods to the `request` object with the "Async" suffix so `request.get()` gets a companion method named `request.getAsync()`.  That new "Async" version returns a promise.  The multiArgs option is not usually needed, but in this case since `request.get()` returns more than one data argument (which is not the usual node async calling convention), it is needed here.

And, here's an implementation of `getMorphite()` that returns a promise and returns the eventual value as the fulfilled value of the promise.

```
function getMorphite() {
    return request.getAsync(crestMarketHistoryMorphite).spread(response, body) {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            var content = JSON.parse(body);
            var topMorphiteBuy;
            var maxBuy = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < content.items.length; i++) {
                var item = content.items[i];
                if (item.location.id == 60003760) {
                    var buyPrice = item.price;
                    if (buyPrice > maxBuy) {
                        maxBuy = buyPrice;
                        topMorphiteBuy = item;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(topMorphiteBuy);
            // return this to make it the fulfilled value of the promise
            return topMorphiteBuy;    
        } else {
            // reject the promise with bad status code
            throw new Error("response.statusCode was: " + response.statusCode)
        }
    });
}
```

If you change the other functions to also work this way, you can then use your original code like this:

```
Promise.all([getTritanium(), getPyrite(), getMexallon(), getIsogen(), 
             getNocxium(), getZydrine(), getMegactye(), getMorphite()])
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log("Response", response);
    allItems.push(response[0]);
    allItems.push(response[1]);
    allItems.push(response[2]);
    allItems.push(response[3]);
    allItems.push(response[4]);
    allItems.push(response[5]);
    allItems.push(response[6]);
    allItems.push(response[7]);
    res.type('application/json');
    res.json(response);
});
```

Comment: `return request.getAsync(crestMarketHistoryMorphite).spread(response,body) {^SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` What you said makes sense and thanks for the great response. Only error im running into is this.

Comment: Also this is how im promisfying the request library `var requestLibrary = require('request');var request = Promise.promisifyAll(requestLibrary, {multiArgs: true});`

Comment: `var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"), {multiArgs: true});` documentation seemed to do it this way and it looked better than my appoarch

Comment: Ok got it
`return request.getAsync(crestMarketHistoryMorphite).spread(function (response, body){` you wernt passing a function in the original spread. it works like this. thanks so much for you help!

Comment: Yes, `var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"), {multiArgs: true});` is best.  You didn't show your `require()` statement so I didn't incorporate that.